# Cannot uninstall SCVMM R2 - Error code 256

Tags: windows-server-2008, scvmm

When I attempt to uninstall SCVMM R2 I receive an error complaining about help/license.rtf. Has anyone seen this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of uninstalling from add/remove programs insert the original installation media and run setup, you should be able to uninstall it from there.

The following is the official microsoft error meaning for code 256:

> 256 VMM cannot load the file %FileName;. The file may be corrupted or missing.
>   Run the Virtual Machine Manager Setup program directly from the product CD. If the setup >program from the CD fails, obtain a new copy of the CD from your vendor.